# List View with multiple image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I am a new android developer And i have created job search application, where i need to display all job with love and like image option, and love and like job saved in my database,

when i hit web service  and display job and also check database is job is exist then set love or like image,

**My problem is that only one image change but i saved/ checked many jobs
Plz Help me how we can handle image in list view**

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         final String description;
         LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         View row =mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,false);
         txtcompany = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_company);
         imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img);
         txtPosition= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_position);
         txtCity= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_city);
         txtState= (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_state);
         txtcompany.setText("Company:  "+companyarray[position]);
         txtPosition.setText("Position: "+positonarray[position]);
         txtCity.setText("City: "+cityarray[position]);
         txtState.setText("State: "+statearray[position]);
         imageView.setTag(receiceValueOfAdapter.get(position));
         description= Descarray[position];

          try{
         //imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starapplied);
         DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
          db.openWritableDatabase();
          savedItems=db.getAllData(str_user);
          if(savedItems.get(0).getid().equals(receiceValueOfAdapter.get(position)))
                  {
                       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starsave);
                  } 
          }catch(Exception e)
          {
             // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
         imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {

                     preferences=getSharedPreferences("LoginActivity", MODE_PRIVATE);
                     str_user=preferences.getString("USERNAME", "DEFAULT");
                     if(str_user !=null && !str_user.equals("DEFAULT"))
                     {
                        try{
                             AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Job_Description.this);
                                    builder.setTitle("Save this Job ?");
                                   // builder.setMessage("whould You like to save job");
                                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // startActivity(new Intent(Job_Description.this,JobSearch.class));
                                         v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starsave); 
                                         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+v.getTag(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                         DBAdapter db = DBAdapter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                                          db.openWritableDatabase();
                                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Status///"+db.getStatus(""+v.getTag(),str_user), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                          if(!db.getStatus(""+v.getTag(),str_user))
                                          {
                                             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
                                          db.insertlocation(v.getTag().toString(),
                                                  txtPosition.getText().toString(),
                                                  txtCity.getText().toString(),
                                                  txtState.getText().toString(), 
                                                  txtcompany.getText().toString(),
                                                  description,
                                                  ""+0,
                                                  str_user,
                                                  str_pass);
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              db.DeleteLocation(v.getTag().toString());
                                              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already In Database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                          }
                                     // Log.e("info", "OK");
                                     }
                                    });
                                    builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                            // Canceled.
                                              dialog.cancel();
                                          }
                                        });
                                    builder.show();
                         }catch(Exception e)
                         {
                             Log.d("Image click", e.toString());
                         }
                     }
                    else
                   {
                         try
                           {
                           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Job_Description.this);
                            builder.setTitle("Get You Job Search Started !");
                           // builder.setMessage("whould You like to save job");
                            builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 startActivity(new Intent(Job_Description.this,LoginActivity.class));
                                 finish();
                                 // Log.e("info", "OK");
                             }
                            });
                            builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    // Canceled.
                                      dialog.cancel();
                                  }
                                });
                            builder.show();
                   } catch(Exception e)
                  {
                     Log.d("Image click", e.toString());
                  }
                   }
                }
            });

         return row;
     }
 }
```

**sorry for bad English Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.**

Comment: are you showing/hiding your images when they are clicked?

Comment: yes but showing/hiding only temporary  when i scroll then set default image, but and i want permanent

Comment: You say only one image is shown so that One image is last one? means the image which you Like/saved is last image store in db?

Comment: tht happen because of this line...  if(savedItems.get(0).getid().equals(receiceValueOfAdapter.get(position)))
                  {
                       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.starsave);
                  } 
          }

Comment: i checked id from database if id is available then listview image is changed

Comment: do you have a default image (starsave or any other) or is it blank?

Comment: default image is starred and i set default image from xml file..my main problem is that only one row's image change but i want to many..

Comment: You have to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` each time you hide/show an image and when you scroll you need to check if you want to show that image based on your DB values. If you don't want to show it you will need to make it `INVISIBLE` explicitly or else it will show default image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you fetch data base value in a loop you fetch only one value